# Connectable Observer: observe termination of all subscribers

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a connectable observer with multiple subscribers.

Each subscriber computes some business logic. For example one of subscribers stores results in database on every `onNext` call, other subscriber accumulates it's results in memory and when `onCompleted` called writes them to file. I want to know when they all finished their work, so I can proceed in doing other stuff (aggregating with other connectable observers, read outputed data from database etc).

This is how I'm observing termination. It's only working because subscribers execute in the same thread as observer.

```
public Observable<Boolean> observeTermination() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        try {
            start();
            return Observable.just(true);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return Observable.just(false);
        }
    });
}

void start() {
    Observable<List<Foo>> fooBatchReaderObservable = fooBatchReader.createObservable(BATCH_SIZE);

    ConnectableObservable<List<Foo>> connectableObservable = fooBatchReaderObservable.publish();
    subscribers.forEach(s -> connectableObservable.subscribe(s));

    connectableObservable.connect();
}
```

So when `observeTermination` gets called I don't want to execute logic in `start` method, but only when someone subscribes to it.
Is there a way to make observation better ?

Well, it's all bad. The problem is that I need to call `connect` on observable somewhere and also return `boolean` results as inication of termination.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer, but it needs the space to explain properly. It would be much easier if you could deal with Observables instead of Subscribers; that gives you much more flexibility in composing them;

Given that you have `components`:

```
Collection<Function<Observable<T>, Observable<?>>> components:
Observable<T> tObs = ... .publish().autoConnect(components.size());
Observable
.from(components)
.flatMap(component -> component.apply(tObs))
.ignoreElements()
.doOnTerminate() // or .defaultIfEmpty(...), or .switchIfEmpty(...)
.subscribe(...);
```

In fact, I'd say you should not even subscribe at all here, just create the observable and return it, let it be usable for composition in other parts of your code.

Comment: I thought about changing subscribers to plain functions that will be called for same data, but this restricts their use to only `onNext`. So there is no way to execute subscriber's logic that left in `onStart`, `onCompleted`, `onError`

Comment: Maybe I can observe `Subsription`s and it's `isUnsubscribe` method ? is there a way to do it ? edit: but there is still a problem with `connect` method

Comment: If you make the subscribers functions that take an observable and generate another observable chain based on the input, you can handle errors, onNext, starts and completes in them.

Comment: I played with sample you provided a little, would you help me to understand how to trigger the tObs to emit items?  Because when i'm subscribing to `Observable.from(components)` it's not called